# How to call child component controller with iteration from parent component controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have similar requirement to this [How to call child component controller function/helper from Parent Component Controller](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/122359/how-to-call-child-component-controller-function-helper-from-parent-component-con/122654#122654?newreg=9b5939d3482645ad84100d419ad955b8) the parent component has a button that will call a function from child component. For more specific, I have function that should show error messages on the individual fields while in the `<aura:iteration>` upon click of Save button.

ParentComponent.cmp

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.listRec}" var="individualRec">
        <c:ChildComponent individualRec="{!individualRec}" aura:id="cComp"/>
    </aura:iteration>
    <button type="button" onclick="{!c.save}">Save</button>
</aura:component>
```

ParentController.js

```
({
    save: function(component, event, helper) {
        var childCmp = component.find("cComp");
        childCmp.sampleMethod();
    }
})
```

ChildComponent.cmp

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:method name="sampleMethod" action="{!c.childSave}" access="PUBLIC" />
    <aura:attribute name="individualRec" type="List" />

    <label>Email</label>
    <ui:inputText aura:id="inputEmail" value="{!v.individualRec.Email}" /
</aura:component>
```

ChildController.js

```
({
    childSave : function(component, event, helper) {
        var inputEmail = component.find("inputEmail");
        var varEmail = inputEmail.get("v.value");
        if ($A.util.isEmpty(varEmail)) {
            inputEmail.set("v.errors", [{message:"Complete this field"}]);
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the child component : `<c:ChildComponent aura:id="cComp"/>` is inside an iteration, which means the child components generated will have the same `aura:id`.

As a result of that, `var childCmp = component.find("cComp");` returns an Array of Child Component instance rather than one Child Component instance.

So you need iterate for the array of child component instances and call their respective *sampleMethod* (`aura:method`).

ParentController.js will look like below:

```
({
    save: function(component, event, helper) {
        var childCmp = component.find("cComp"); // return array
        for(var i = 0;i < childComp.length;i++){
            childCmp[i].sampleMethod();
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Hi Praveen - I added this code but it throws an error "[childComp is not defined]"

Comment: Can you check your code again?. It might be a typo error: as per the answer it should be "childCmp" instead of "childComp"

Comment: @Von did you figure out the solution