# Can't get Component Action to style properly (modal footer+ select options)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css, lightning-design-system, modal

I'm a CSS newbie, so this might be a trivial question. Nonetheless I need help.

I have this Lightning component used as action on a button.

```
<aura:component controller="..." access="GLOBAL" implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

    <div class="slds-page-header" role="banner">
        <p class="slds-text-heading--label">{!v.record.Name}</p>
        <h1 class="slds-page-header__title slds-m-right--small slds-truncate slds-align-left">Add new year</h1>
    </div>

   <c:strike_select aura:id="options" value="{!v.selected}" placeholder="Select Template" onchange="{!c.doSelect}">
        <aura:renderIf isTrue="{!v.showBlank}">
            <c:strike_option value="" label="No Template (Create blank record)" />
        </aura:renderIf>

        <aura:iteration items="{!v.templates}" var="tmpl">
            <c:strike_option value="{!tmpl.id}" label="{!tmpl.label}" />
        </aura:iteration>
    </c:strike_select>

    <lightning:button label="Cancel" onclick="{!c.doCancel}" variant="neutral"  />
    <lightning:button label="Continue" onclick="{!c.doContinue}" variant="brand" /> 
</aura:component>
```

The initalization code that populates the options:

```
({
    doInit : function(cmp, event, helper) {    
        var action = cmp.get("c.getOptions");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            cmp.set("v.templates", response.getReturnValue());
            cmp.find("options").blur(); // fails!
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action); 
    }
```

But as you see in the screenshots there are three display problems.

1. The select **options are auto-opened** on page load
2. The select **options are hidden** outside of the modal (showing 2 ugly scrollbars
3. **Insufficient spacing** between header, select and buttons. How can I make it look like a real modal. I read everything about mimicing modals but I could make it work.

Note: I am using [Strike Components](https://github.com/appiphony/Strike-Components) here as making it work with pure Design System is not what I want and Base Components also don't style properly.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Item 1:** To make spacing use slds classes: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/margin/#react-target (similar for padding)

```
<div class="slds-m-top_medium">
        <lightning:button label="Cancel" onclick="{!c.doCancel}" variant="neutral"  />
        <lightning:button label="Continue" onclick="{!c.doContinue}" variant="brand" /> 
    </div>
```

**Item 3:** To get your dropdown items on top of modal, it's z-index property has to be larger than modal's z-index. Use browser developer tools to inspect z-index of your modal and assign greater value to any element in your modal body that contains dropdown.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

**Item 2:** Here is my code for opening modal:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="public">
    <aura:attribute name="selected" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="templates" type="Object[]" default="[{'id': '1', 'label': 'one'}, {'id': '2', 'label': 'two'}]" />

    <c:strike_modal aura:id="modal"
            title="Confirmation"
            secondaryButtonLabel="Cancel"
            primaryButtonLabel="Ok"
            showHeader="true"
            showFooter="true"
            showModal="false">

            <c:strike_select aura:id="options" value="{!v.selected}" label="My label" placeholder="Select Template">
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.templates}" var="tmpl">
                    <c:strike_option value="{!tmpl.id}" label="{!tmpl.label}" />
                </aura:iteration>
            </c:strike_select>

    </c:strike_modal>

    <lightning:button label="Click me!" onclick="{!c.click}" class="slds-m-around--x-large"/>

</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    click: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.find("modal").show();
    }
})
```

Result:[image]
When your component is loaded from quick action, it looks like this is platform feature that first form element is focused. To prevent this you can try this walkaround:

```
<div tabindex="0" ></div>
<c:strike_select aura:id="options" value="{!v.selected}" label="My label" placeholder="Select Template">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.templates}" var="tmpl">
        <c:strike_option value="{!tmpl.id}" label="{!tmpl.label}"/>
    </aura:iteration>
</c:strike_select>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

Comment: Cool. Only problem 1 is unsolved. I tried to blur the element as it is focused by populating it in onInit(). But calling cmp.find("options").getElement().blur(); fails with an error.

Comment: @RobertSösemann Try without getElement(), cmp.find returns lightning component itself, method blur() is available on it, but getElement() returns DOM element.

Comment: "cmp.find(...).blur is not a function" Please see the code above. I am using a Strike Select defined here: https://github.com/appiphony/Strike-Components/blob/master/aura/strike_select/strike_select.cmp

Comment: @RobertSösemann Oh, I think this is what Salesforce does not allow to do - to call component's method from other component (kind of security/isolation). In this case you have to call component's method from component's controller or helper. Or you have to define aura:method  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/122359/how-to-call-child-component-controller-function-helper-from-parent-component-con

Comment: You mean I cannot even blur the parent component <c:strike_select aura:id="...">? althought it is not an internal of the component?

Comment: Try adding this line to strike_select: <aura:method name="blur" access="global" action="{!c.blur}" /> and after it try calling blur() as above. Worked for me.

Comment: Modifying the external library code? But then I would have to do is with every update of the library. Isn't there a way to make this work from outside? E.g. having an invisible element in the page that "pulls the focus away"?

Comment: Can you share the whole code of popup and code that opens it?

Comment: It works when I create a Strike modal like in your code. But when I call it from an Action implementing lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader which brings its native modal the problem still exists.

Comment: I see, looks like this is default lightning behaviour - it makes first element focused when component is loaded from action

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60001/discussion-between-robert-sosemann-and-vladyslav-kushney).